# How To Specify A Cell To The Left Of Another Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I currently have an expense worksheet. I input dates, costs and reasons into columns A,B and C respectively. I want to make a cell that automatically adds values from Column B provided the proper reason is in column C. Basically, every time column C says "Gas" I was cell F1 to add the values of the corresponding B column. Can INDEX and MATCH be used for this or do I need to use some other method?

Comment: Sounds like you need `SUMIF`, but it would be 100% clear with some sample data and the expected result. Try `=SUMIF(C:C,"Gas",B:B)`.

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question out - use `SUMIF`.

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"Gas",B:B)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!